# How to use 'args = parser.parse_args()' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In cmd, I can run the code by calling

```
python '...file path and name...' --task=tsp --nodes=10
```

because of `args = parser.parse_args()`, and this can transform the input into program

Now, I want to run in jupyter notebook, and I rewrite the code `args = parser.parse_args()` as

I tried the code as follows, while it doesn't work

```
args = ['--task','tsp','--nodes','10']
```

So what should I rewrite the code?

Thanks!

Comment: `args = parser.parse_args(['--task','tsp','--nodes','10'])` should work

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot!